# Why can't I use pair as key of unordered_set / unordered_map?

Tags: c++, dictionary, set, unordered-map, unordered-set

Both `std::set<>` and `std::map<>` can use a `std::pair` as a key, but why can't `std::unordered_set<>` and `std::unordered_map<>`?

For example:

```
unordered_set<pair<int,int> > S;
S.insert(make_pair(0, 1));
```

Does not compile.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The `unordered_*` containers need a hash function. By default, they use `std::hash` but there is no specialization of `std::hash` for `std::pair<T1,T2>` provided in the standard library. On the other hand, the *ordered* containers rely on `std::less` (by default) and `std::pair` *does* have `operator<` provided. That's why it just works.

In order to have an unordered container with a `pair`, you will have to provide a hash functor yourself. For example:

```
struct SimpleHash {
    size_t operator()(const std::pair<int, int>& p) const {
        return p.first ^ p.second;
    }
};

std::unordered_set<std::pair<int, int>, SimpleHash> S;
S.insert(std::make_pair(0, 1));
```

Comment: would S.emplace(... also work, and if not, what would you change?

Comment: @Barry can p.first ^ p.second get the same value for different pairs like  p_a and p_b?

Comment: @olivia Of course. It'll definitely give you the same value for `(a,b)` and `(b,a)`. It's not intended to be a perfect hash function, just a simple example.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide a hash function for pair.